using a pipe symbol in a jq command throws an error
I am having a shell script file validation-example.sh , it has the followign content
expected_template = '{
  "remoteIds": [
    {
      "remoteId": "",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    }
  ]
}'

actual_json = '{
  "remoteIds": [
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:1:0:0:0:12]--(http://fd00-10-244-1--12.test.pod:8080)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:1:0:0:0:12]--(http://fd00-10-244-1--12.test.pod:8081)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:1:0:0:0:12]--(http://fd00-10-244-1--12.test.pod:8082)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    },
    {
      "remoteId": "[fd00:10:244:1:0:0:0:12]--(http://fd00-10-244-1--12.test.pod:8083)",
      "requestsReceived": 1
    }
  ]
}'

validate_json() {
    local data="$1"
    local template="$2"
    jq -e "$data | $template" >/dev/null
}


if validate_json "$actual_json" "$expected_template"; then
    echo "The actual JSON matches the expected template."
else
    echo "The actual JSON does not match the expected template."
fi

However when i run the file it is returning the following error
validation-example.sh: line 1: expected_template: command not found
validation-example.sh: line 22: actual_json: command not found
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
 |  
jq: 1 compile error
The actual JSON does not match the expected template.

any help please
thanks

What shell scripting environment is this? [tag:bash], [tag:zsh], etc

If [tag:bash], there should not be spaces around the = when assigning variable values

Please copy/paste your code with a proper first line (!#/bin/sh or whatever) into https://shellcheck.net and fix any flagged errors. If that doesn't resolve your problem update your question with the correct code and indicate "#shellcheck approved" or similar. Good luck.

Does this answer your question? Why does the equal to operator not work if it is not surrounded by spaces?

Does this answer your question? Command not found error in Bash variable assignment

Also,  we only need one line of sample data and template to debug this problem. Please read  the section How to turn a bad script into a good question (this advice applies to all languages, not just sh/bash/ksh)

When shell scripting in sh, bash and similar shells, you can't put spaces around the = during assignment.  If you do, it tries to find a command equal to the name of the variable you're trying to assign.  You'll see this in the first two error messages that end with ": command not found".
The next problem is that since the variables aren't assigned because of the first two errors, you're attempting to run "jq " | " which jq can't parse.
Final note, I haven't used jq enough to encounter this problem, but with your command, it's still reading from stdin, so you don't get any output until you hit ctrl-d to signal end of file or redirect stdin.  </dev/null works in unix-like OS.

Remove the white spaces around your assignments for expected_template and actual_json. Edit it to:
actual_json='{ 
expected_template='{
learn more form here

If this is answered by another post, vote to close as a duplicate
